# Initialization of vector of vectors

Tags: c++, vector

```
vector<vector<int>>dp(3);
for(int i = 0; i<3; i++) {
    vector<int>price(10);
    dp.push_back(price);
}
```

It is showing error while initialization. Can anyone explain the reason behind this wrong code?

Comment: What error exactly? You need to either remove `(3)` **or** replace `.push_back(...)` with `.[i] = ...` because now your vector ends up with 6 elements, first 3 of them empty.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue. You'll end up a vector `dp` with size `6` of course: the first 3 elements are empty vectors (the elements initialized with the default constructor in the constructor of the outer vector) and the following 3 have size 10...

Comment: Note: If the goal is a matrix you may find you get higher performance with a single contiguous block masquerading as a 2D structure. [See this linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/4581301) for a simple way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

If what you intend is declaring an empty two dimensional `vector[3][10]`, you can do it at once.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> dp(3,std::vector<int>(10));
    std::cout<<dp.size(); //3
    std::cout<<std::endl<<dp[0].size(); //10
}
```

Then you can assign values to it by using something like `dp[0][4]=12;` or with loops.

Answer (score 2):

This statement

```
vector<vector<int>>dp(3);
```

create a vector `dp` with `3` default constructed `int` vectors and in loop, you are doing

```
dp.push_back(price);
```

the `push_back()` appends the given vector value to the end of the container. So, after loop, you will end up having `dp` vector of size `6`, out of which first `3` are empty vectors and last `3` are vectors of `10` `int` elements.

Instead of specifying `size`, you can use `reserve()` to reserver the storage:

```
vector<vector<int>>dp;
dp.reserve(3);
for(int i = 0; i<3; i++) {
    vector<int>price(10);
    dp.push_back(price);   // A suggestion: check emplace_back
}
```

To create a vector of `3` vectors, each having `10` `int` elements, you can simply do:

```
vector<vector<int> >dp (3, vector<int>(10));
```

Also, if you want to initialise all elements with some value, say `-1`, you can do:

```
vector<vector<int> >dp (3, vector<int>(10, -1));
```